# Not able to access variables outside ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, jsonp

I am accessing json data from other domain using JSONP with callback function.

I am able to access data and in success function i am pushing json data to a array (items[ ]) but i am not able to access that array outside ajax call function.

How can i access the Items[ ] array outside ajax call. below is the code.

Thanks in advance

```
$.ajaxSetup({ "async": false });

            var items = [];


            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://aaa.com/.wrf=callback",
                //data: "{}",
                crossDomain: true,
                jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function (msg) {

                    $.each(msg.response.docs, function (key, value) {

                        items.push([this["ID"]]);

                        return items;

                    });
                },

                async: false,
                error: function (msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Did you try `window.items = [];`

Comment: `async: false` is not a good idea in almost all cases. Nevertheless, how did you check that you are _not able to access that array outside ajax call function_?

Comment: @zazu I did not try this.should i declare the items array in this way to access it outside ajax call function..?

Comment: @Regent after the ajax call function just tried to alert items array it returns me empty and if i alert items array just after push code it returns me the json data

Comment: I would say yes, as `async: false` is extremely bad practice and the question I marked as duplicate explains several better patterns to use instead.

Comment: Thats by design - a JSONP request *has* to be `async` by its very nature.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan well, yes, I have finally found it in docs, sorry.